# Cast list of object into list of class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, casting, observablecollection

I have `ObservableCollection` from class named A. (`ObservableCollection<A>)`.
This collection (lets call it listA) is binded to `ListBox` (lets call it `itemsList`).
This `ListBox` has SelectionMode=Extended, so I want to be able to select multiple items.
I'm trying to get the selected items of that `itemsList`. The problem is that the `SelectedItems` returns list of objects, and I dont know how to "convert" it to `ObservableCollection` from class A.
I need to put it in the xml, for instance, if I have a `TextBox` binded to string in class A.
Example:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=itemsList, Path=SelectedItems.stringA}"/>
```

And of course that I have the `DataContext` to that `TextBox`

Comment: Which instance property of ClassA you want to show in textbox then?

Comment: I have a string thats called stringA, with get and set methods, if thats what you mean. Sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: No, i meant suppose you have two items selected in your listbox. Then of the two selectedItems, which item's stringA property text needs to be shown in textbox?

Comment: I want the value of stringA to be the same as the first SelectedItem.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm not sure that I really understand this whole workaround.

Comment: @amirm - So answer i posted earlier, did that only. What's an issue with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this binding:

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="MyTextBox"
    TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged"
    Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItems[0].Content, 
    ElementName=MyListBox,
    NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
    Mode=TwoWay}">
</TextBox>
```

You will need TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged event handler, which will look like this:

```
private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<A>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Content = MyTextBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `StringA` from the first selected item, you can try with binding to index in collection. Something like this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=itemsList, Path=SelectedItems[0].stringA}"/>
```

Comment: Tried it. It works with single selection but when selecting multiple items and editing the textbox, only the first item changed, while I wanted also all the other selecteditems.stringA to be the same as the first selecteditem.stringA

Comment: Well thats a different and more complicated story.I don't think you can solve that with some simple Binding. You will need some more logic, maybe another object that knows the value in the textbox and what items are selected. If you have that then you can update the property in all the selected items.